# Showing only one tooltip for all. Highstock highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highstock module, indicator module and highcharts into my angular application. For example , here's the option of my highstock chart with indicator.

```
this.stock = new StockChart({
  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 1
  },
  title: {
    text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
  },
  series: [{
    tooltip: {
      valueDecimals: 2
    },
    name: 'AAPL',
    id: 'AAPL',
    type: 'candlestick',
    data: [
      [1487635200000, 2354.909912, 2366.709961, 2354.909912, 2365.379883],
      [1487721600000, 2361.110107, 2365.129883, 2358.340088, 2362.820068],
      [1487808000000, 2367.5, 2368.26001, 2355.090088, 2363.810059],
      [1487894400000, 2355.72998, 2367.340088, 2352.870117, 2367.340088],
      [1488153600000, 2365.22998, 2371.540039, 2361.870117, 2369.75],
      [1488240000000, 2366.080078, 2367.790039, 2358.959961, 2363.639893],
      [1488326400000, 2380.129883, 2400.97998, 2380.129883, 2395.959961],
      [1488412800000, 2394.75, 2394.75, 2380.169922, 2381.919922],
      [1488499200000, 2380.919922, 2383.889893, 2375.389893, 2383.120117],
      [1488758400000, 2375.22998, 2378.800049, 2367.97998, 2375.310059],
      [1488844800000, 2370.73999, 2375.120117, 2365.51001, 2368.389893],
      [1488931200000, 2369.810059, 2373.090088, 2361.01001, 2362.97998],
      [1489017600000, 2363.48999, 2369.080078, 2354.540039, 2364.870117],
      [1489104000000, 2372.52002, 2376.860107, 2363.040039, 2372.600098],
      [1489363200000, 2371.560059, 2374.419922, 2368.52002, 2373.469971],
      [1489449600000, 2368.550049, 2368.550049, 2358.179932, 2365.449951],
      [1489536000000, 2370.340088, 2390.01001, 2368.939941, 2385.26001],
      [1489622400000, 2387.709961, 2388.100098, 2377.179932, 2381.379883],
      [1489708800000, 2383.709961, 2385.709961, 2377.639893, 2378.25],
      [1489968000000, 2378.23999, 2379.550049, 2369.659912, 2373.469971],
      [1490054400000, 2379.320068, 2381.929932, 2341.899902, 2344.02002],
      [1490140800000, 2343, 2351.810059, 2336.449951, 2348.449951],
      [1490227200000, 2345.969971, 2358.919922, 2342.129883, 2345.959961],
      [1490313600000, 2350.419922, 2356.219971, 2335.73999, 2343.97998],
      [1490572800000, 2329.110107, 2344.899902, 2322.25, 2341.590088],
      [1490659200000, 2339.790039, 2363.780029, 2337.629883, 2358.570068],
      [1490745600000, 2356.540039, 2363.360107, 2352.939941, 2361.129883],
      [1490832000000, 2361.310059, 2370.419922, 2358.580078, 2368.060059],
      [1490918400000, 2364.820068, 2370.350098, 2362.600098, 2362.719971],
      [1491177600000, 2362.340088, 2365.870117, 2344.72998, 2358.840088],
      [1491264000000, 2354.76001, 2360.530029, 2350.719971, 2360.159912],
      [1491350400000, 2366.590088, 2378.360107, 2350.52002, 2352.949951],
      [1491436800000, 2353.790039, 2364.159912, 2348.899902, 2357.48999],
      [1491523200000, 2356.590088, 2363.76001, 2350.73999, 2355.540039],
      [1491782400000, 2357.159912, 2366.370117, 2351.5, 2357.159912]
    ]
  }, {
    type: 'sma',
    linkedTo: 'AAPL',
    params: { period: 5 }
  }]
});
```

}

this code looks like this

[image: Stock Chart]

If you see, there are two tooltips. One for the candlestick series and another one for SMA series. I want to merge these two tooltips into one in such a way that in one tooltip after open , high , low , close values. SMA series name and the value should come. I tried to do using tooltip formatter but maybe I am missing something so it is not coming in the way I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to play with the `tooltip.shared` and `tooltip.split` parameters? Here is the code:

```
tooltip: {
  split: false,
  shared: true
},
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/s8m90bjt/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.shared

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.split